# Telnet reconnect or maintain session?

Tags: telnet

We currently have several RFID Scanners connected to the backend via a telnet client.
However due to coverage of our wifi these scanners might lose there connection for a small period of time.

The devices now disconnect and fail to restart their telnet application unless restarted.

Is there a way to allow a connection drop in the telnet sessions and let them auto reconnect without their sessions being terminated immediatly?

Comment: Have you tried to increase timouts or intervals? Maybe this helps: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-change-the-default-timeout-settings-for-telnet-session-in-centos-rhel/

Comment: Thanks, i will try these. Any suggestion on Idle session timeout?

Comment: No, not really, I guess you'll have to try some config changes and see how the environment reacts to them.